# Use a provider to run a command onEntet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router to change states in an AngularJS application.  I have a provider that uses JavaScript to create a graph in the HTML where a div exists.  Only one of the views has the div element used by my graph provider, so I want to call graphProvider.drawGraph() when I go to that state.

I'm struggling to get the graph to draw: the error I'm getting is, "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dataPortalApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module graphProvider due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'graphProvider' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

My router.js looks like:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('dataPortalApp')
    .config(DataPortalRouter);

  DataPortalRouter.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 'graphProvider'];

  function DataPortalRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, graphProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/views/_dashboard.html',
    onEnter: function() {
      graphProvider.drawGraph()
    }
  })
  .state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/_index.html'
  });

  }//end DataPortalRouter

})();
```

My app,js looks like:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('dataPortalApp', ['ui.router', 'graphProvider']);
})();
```

Any help is very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all of your module scripts are being imported and in the right order. The *new* order should be:

1. angular.js
2. angular-ui-router.js
3. app.js
4. graphProvider.js (after app.js as it's part of your module, not another module as I originally thought.)

And remove the module dependency for `graphProvider`:

App.js:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('dataPortalApp', ['ui.router']);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Now I get `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'dataPortalApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`  I can't seem to win - if I put the app first, it wants the provider.  If I put the provider first, it says the app is unavailable.  More code is here

https://github.com/tmurphree/projectFilter/tree/dev 

if you have a chance to look.

Comment: @tmurphree I've corrected my original answer. Looking at your full code, `graphProvider.js` should go after `app.js` as that declares the module that you are attaching the graphProvider to (my mistake sorry). Going back to the original error, I think it's just becuse you were trying to inject the provider as a module and it's complaining because it's not a module, so just remove that from app.js.

Comment: You are the **man**!  That totally fixed it!  Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Excellent, please mark as answer if this helped. Thanks